# Getting an int array out of a 2d object array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am creating a tile game and I save each tile as an int array. I represent the board with a 2d object array and then I save the 2d object array into a file using object output stream.

I can get the value of the object array, but not the int array stored in it. I need the integers stored in the integer array.

```
public Start()
{
    Object[][] tileBoard = WorldIO.loadWorld( "A player named file");
    int[] singleTile = tileBoard[0][0]; //the error
}
```

It is asking me if I want to cast it to int[], but that still does not work.

Comment: What's `p`? And what does `WorldIO.loadWorld()` return?

Comment: Why are you representing the board as an `Object` array if you want it to be an `int` array?

Comment: Sorry, p is supposed to be tileBoard and WorldIO.loadWorld() returns an object array that is read from a file

Comment: Assuming `p`is a 2d array, `p[n][k]` will give you a single value, not an array. (with n, k any integer matching the array's size)

Comment: You try to say `int[] = Object` which shouldn't work as said. Also, don't just tell error, instead show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your code, I am assuming we are dealing with Integers and tileBoard is a 2D array of Integers.

When you wrote tileBoard[0][0], the type that is returned is an **Integer** and you are trying to save that Integer as an Integer **array**, therefore the types **do not match**. Try doing `int [] array = 5` for example, you will get an error.

- If what you wanted to do was to save that single integer at tileBoard[0][0] in an array, all you have to do is `int [] singleTile = {tileBoard[0][0]};`By adding the curly braces, you are now saving an integer inside an integer array.
- If what you wanted to do was to extract an entire array from the 2D array and save that array into your singleTile object, you should use a for loop.

Here is what you can do

```
int lengthOfRow = tileBoard[0].length;//Getting the length of the row at row 0
int [] singleTile = new int[lengthOfRow]//Defining length of your new array
for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfRow; i++){
     int add = tileBoard[0][i];
     singleTile[i] = add;//Adding the elements to your single array
}
```

If you think of a 2D array as a grid with rows and columns, what you can do is pick a row and move through it using a for loop (using a pen and paper will help you visualize it). Since your new array will be identical to a row inside your 2D array, they must have the same length. First you have to get that length and initiate your new array accordingly. Then you loop over the columns, int add is first at tileBoard[0][0] then tileBoard[0][1] then tileBoard[0][2], until there are no more elements in that row.